# How can we have "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" construct in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Couldn't find any any decent way of adding this construct at model level.

Primary aim is to do "insert_or_update", but don't want to do read => check existence => write or update from ActiveRecord layer.

Any pointers ?

Found some related deprecated code though.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create_or_update
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

Answer (score -2):

You're after [first_or_initialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize), which you can combine with a where, as in:

```
instance = Model.where(:attr1 => 'value1').first_or_initialize(:attr2 => 'value2')
# do something with instance
instance.save
```

If you don't have to operate on the instance before saving it, you can also use [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)

Comment: This is different than `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` since it does not provide the same atomic guarantees